# Using multiple git projects in the same repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

I've built a static website setup that I'm trying to make modular, so I can use the same basic site for multiple websites and simply use configuration files to make each site different.  My current setup is to have each site on a separate branch (`site1`, `site2`, etc.) and merge the common files into `master`.  However, it's become kind of a mess, since whenever I make an edit for `site1` and want to add it into `site2`, I end up having to do a lot of legwork to disentangle the `site1` configurations from the common code.

What I would really like is if there was a way so I can keep my common files (e.g. `index.html`, `page.html`, `angular.js`) in one container, and then several other containers for the site-specific files (e.g. `main.css`, `config.json`, `pretty-pic.jpg`).  I would like to be able to track these containers separately, so if I want to edit, say, `index.html`, I can do that without affecting the site-specific containers, and when I want to customize something on a site (e.g. some CSS), I can do that without it affecting the main code or the other site's code.

I've examined submodules, but those appear to tie one repository into another, and I really need my main code to not be linked to only one of the sites.  Plus, I need the `index.html` and my other main files in the top directory, not in any subdirectory.  I've also looked at keeping multiple repositories in the same directory locally, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way.

What is the best way in git to achieve what I'm trying to do?  I'd prefer a cross-platform solution, but I can settle for just Linux.  These files will eventually need to be dropped into AWS S3, if that affects the solution.

Comment: Submodules can be used by any number of other repositories and are very useful for library type repositories.

Comment: From what I understand, though, I would need to add my main code as a submodule to `site1`, `site2`, etc., and then the main code would be in a subdirectory, correct?

Comment: Yes, but you could have some kind of "build" that moved or copied files into the right places to be used and ignore those files in the "site" repository. I don't think you are going to get a perfect fit with any "built-in" tools in Git.

Comment: What I can suggest, having each project has submodule and that is easy to maintain.